# How to return an image file correctly using nest.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, nestjs

I'm trying to return the requested image file. My client is downloading the file, but I can't display it because it's an invalid `png` file. If I open the stored file `tmpFile.png`, I can see it correctly. So probably the problem is on how I'm sending it back to the client asking for it.

```
// This is my controller
async getFile(@Param('bucketname') bucketName: string,
            @Param('filename') fileName: string) {
return await this.appService.getFile(bucketName, fileName);


// This is the function called
getFile(bucketName: string, fileName: string) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.minioClient.getObject(bucketName, fileName, (e, dataStream) => {
        if (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }

        let size = 0;
        const binary = fs.createWriteStream('tmpFile.png');

        dataStream.on('data', chunk => {
          size += chunk.length;
          binary.write(chunk);
        });
        dataStream.on('end', () => {
          binary.end();
          resolve(binary);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54607278/nestjs-return-a-fie-from-gridfs

Comment: Title is misleading. It should have been specified as "[AWS] return image file correctly using nestjs"

Comment: Why it should be aws?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should works:

```
// This is my controller
async getFile(@Param('bucketname') bucketName: string, @Param('filename') fileName: string, @Res() response) {
  return (await this.appService.getFile(bucketName, fileName)).pipe(response);
}
```